# Weird behavior with defines for usleep() and inet_aton()

Tags: c, module

I have created two modules: `files.h` and `connection.h`.

`files.h` is included in `connection.h`.

`files.h` uses `usleep()` function and `connection.h` uses `inet_aton()` function at some point of the respective `.c` files. Those functions need the following defines:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

So, as `files.h` is included in `connection.h`, I thought I could just write those defines in `files.h` but when I compile I get the following error:

> connection.c:23:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘inet_aton’

So I decided to try to write those defines in `connection.h` instead of `files.h` just to compile and get the following error:

> files.c:298:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usleep’

At this point, my next option was writing the defines in the respective `.c` files to solve this. But instead, I got this error while compiling:

> files.c:302:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘usleep’

> connection.c:23:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘inet_aton’

I don't understand what's the issue. How can I use both functions?

**files.h**

```
#ifndef _FILES_H_
#define _FILES_H_

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

// ...

#endif
```

**connection.h**

```
#ifndef _CONNECTION_H_
#define _CONNECTION_H_

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include "files.h"

#include <ctype.h>
#include <pthread.h>


// ...

#endif
```

Comment: Your posted `files.h` doesn't contain the specified macro definitions. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please note that any symbol beginning with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter is reserved. See point 3 in [this reserved identifier list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers).

Comment: Define  _XOPEN_SOURCE 500, _POSIX_C_SOURCE and _GNU_SOURCE *before* including any header files that might use them.

Comment: That's my bad, I edited the question again. The issue I described happened with the defines before the includes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue writing the defines above the includes thanks to your suggestions BUT in the `.c` files. Still not working if I write the defines anywhere in the `.h` files.

**files.c**

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include "files.h"
```

**connection.c**

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include "connection.h"
```

Comment: You haven't provided the top section of those .c files. I assume you have several includes there as well, before including connection.h or files.h, but I can only guess at this point. Please note that you should generally not mess around defining these SOURCE versions, but use a proper build system that does this for you. For example Cmake or GNU auto tools.

Comment: All the includes in the .c files are included in their respective .h files so I just need to include the .h file in the .c file. Also I'll check out the alternatives you suggested, thanks

Comment: I believe you when you say they are included, but be sure to check whether you have included any system-includes such as unistd.h before files.h or connection.h.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an ordering issue..

When you include in this way:

```
#include <unistd.h>   // other includes as well
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

The header files are brought in without the override defines.

However, the purpose of the defines is to change what functions/signatures are imported from the headers!
And since C is very linear, the order matters..

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>   // other includes as well
```

Basically, define your requests first, before you include any standard header file.

These must be included before the FIRST TIME the header is seen -
So if 'connection.c' includes something before connection.h, then the defines may not be present for the first include of <unistd.h>